# Get-Package is missing Path parameter

Tags: powershell-extensions

Weirdly, in one of my script I am trying to do such a call:

```
Get-Package -Path "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Platform.dev.local\App_Data\packages\This.File.Was.JustCreated.xml"
```

but what I get in return is:

> Get-Package : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Path'.

Given XML file **does** exist. Moreover, that same script should have access to it as it was that script itself who generated this file on the previous step.

Why so?

The [documentation](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/packaging/get-package) is confusing: it says that Get-Package "**Loads the package definition (xml) from the specified path**." but the demo shows that it is trying to get from an item. In any case, the error is unable to get a parameter value.

Answer (score -1):

The right way of calling is without `-Path` parameter at all:

`Get-Package "This.File.Was.JustCreated.xml"`

That means, documentation should be corrected, as it claims `-Path` parameter is mandatory, while it is not, plus the rest of things from my initial question

Comment: @rich_seal Thank you for the precise answer in Slack, that actually sorted this out!

Comment: The documentation is correct in that the parameter is required. While this is a positional parameter, I always recommend you keep the parameter name shown. The reason it broke is not yet known; the issue appears to be related to using the full path.

Comment: Why does it then work without a parameter (as I stated in my answer) and does not work when specifying, also why does parameter require item path rather than xml file? Seriously, it is confusing